# how to display image in a grid using C# for WP8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i need to insert an image in a WP8. i have a stack of images. once i click the image, it has to be set as background for a grid. so i created an empty "grid1" and button. wrote the  below code in the button click event, but the image doesnot get displayed !

```
 private void bg6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(
            new Uri("\\PhoneApp2\\PhoneApp2\\Assets\\bg\\bg5.jpg"));
        myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
       // Grid grid1 = new Grid();
        grid1.Background = myBrush;          
    }
```

Comment: Where your grid1 is situated on the page? Are you sure your image is correctly loaded?

Comment: @Haspemulator i added my grid1 inside an canvas.                  <Canvas Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="800"> <grid1>...</grid1>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to use Image to fill the background from URI.

```
private void bg6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush(new Uri("\\PhoneApp2\\PhoneApp2\\Assets\\bg\\bg5.jpg"));
   // Grid grid1 = new Grid();
    grid1.Background = myBrush;          
}
```

Second, it is a WAY better to design it in XAML and manipulate it visibility and source from code by creating the helper class with visibility and source property. Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface into that class.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" DataContext="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibleProperty}">
<Grid.Background>
<ImageBrush x:Name="myBrush" ImageSource="{Binding Path=SourceProperty}"></ImageBrush>
</Grid.Background>
```

And in code:

```
private void bg6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myGrid.DataContext=new myImagePresenterClass(new Uri("\\PhoneApp2\\PhoneApp2\\Assets\\bg\\bg5.jpg"), Visibility.Visible)
}

public class myImagePresenterClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private URI sourceProperty
Public URI SourceProperty
{
get
 {
  return sourceProperty;
 }
set
 {
   sourceProperty=value;
   if(PropertyChanged!=null){PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SourceProperty"));}
 }
}

//Don't forget to implement the Visible property the same way as SourceProperty and the class constructor.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to know if your image file is in the correct place and set to the right build type. I'd suggest adding an event handler to the [Image failed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
private void bg6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
  Image image = new Image();
  image.ImageFailed += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Failed to load: " + e.ErrorException.Message);
  image.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(
  new Uri("\\PhoneApp2\\PhoneApp2\\Assets\\bg\\bg5.jpg"));
  myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
  // Grid grid1 = new Grid();
  grid1.Background = myBrush;          
}
```

Comment: i placed my image in the correct location. but no use. i'm very week at handling exceptions. so could you please tell me clearly how to handle the ImageFailed exception. it shows an message like this      "An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: `code`  private void bg6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
            Image image = new Image();
            image.ImageFailed += (s, i) => MessageBox.Show("Failed to load: " + i.ErrorException.Message);
            image.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(
                new Uri(
                   "\\Assets\\bg\\bg5.jpg"));
            myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
           // Grid grid1 = new Grid();
            grid1.Background = myBrush;          
        }

Comment: That message is telling you that your Uri is invalid. It is hard to know what your exact Uri should be since you haven't given us information about where the file is. I'd suggest changing it to relative like this new Uri("[Your Path"], UriKind.Relative).

Comment: hi i placed my image file inside the assets folder of VS.net 2012. its located within the project folder only. the main problem is, i couldnt load the image uri through C# by click of an button.

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake... i'm sorry guys. i didn't follow the syntax correctly. i missed the '@' in the Uri method. the correct way to represent this is

```
 private void bg1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.ImageFailed += (s, i) => MessageBox.Show("Failed to load: " + i.ErrorException.Message);
        image.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/bg/bg1.jpg/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
        grid1.Background = myBrush;

    }
```