# How to structure and edit images that are in an xaml grid and adjust them in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've been searching around for methods to manage grided images through c sharp and xaml. So far what I've read is to use xaml and then edit it with c sharp instead of creating everything in c sharp for xaml to use. ([how to display image in a grid using C# for WP8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467762/how-to-display-image-in-a-grid-using-c-sharp-for-wp8))
It's quiet possible what I'm looking for is described here, and I'm missing/not-understanding it.

My first rather blind attempt at this was to just create a class and give it factors in c sharp to then use and implement on the created images in xaml.

What I'm wondering is if there is a better way to "sync" the two. For example if the user tapped one of the images Is there an easy way to tell which one they tapped as far as the myGridSpace [0] or [1].

So far the way I've been determining is calling a method that searches for matching coordinates to what I give it I.E: FindGridWithMethod(0,0,0,0); public int FindGridWithMethod(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
//For Loops until found return either 0 or 1
The trouble is, I still have to manually type this into each image_tapped method, it feels disjointed and I'm looking for better unity.

I've written up an example, my main project has a grid of at **least** 4 x 4.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public class GridSpaces
        {
            //Margin
            public int fromLeft;
            public int fromRight;
            public int fromTop;
            public int fromBottom;
            //Who is in this square
            public String occupiedBy;
            //The image for the grid space
            public String sourceImage;


        }
GridSpaces[] myGridSpaces = new GridSpaces[2];
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {


            myGridSpaces[i] = new GridSpaces()

            {
                OccupiedBy = "Nothing",
//GreenCellBorder is a string containing the file source of the image
                sourceImage = GreenCellBorder
//Insert Margin Variables Here

            };

        }
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }

        private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Image_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="43,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/First Action.png" Tapped="Image_Tapped"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="159,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/Second Action.png" Tapped="Image_Tapped_1"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Image.Tag property to store your instance of GridSpaces. For example:
Give the name of each Image, and attach the same event ImageTapped

```
         <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  Margin="43,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/First Action.png" Tapped="ImageTapped"/>
                <Image x:Name="image2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"  Margin="159,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/Second Action.png" Tapped="ImageTapped"/>

            </Grid>
```

Then in code for initalization:

```
image1.Tag = new GridSpaces();
image2.Tag = new GridSpaces();
```

Code for handle tap event:

```
 private void ImageTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // cast to image
        var img = (Image)sender;
        var yourObj = (GridSpaces)img.Tag;
    }
```

Another thing besides of this:
You should research about binding in WPF,  for each GrindSpaces will be bound to the Image , so that if you add a new GrindSpaces instance in your Context, the list Images will be updated synchronously

Comment: Binding in WPF, I'll definitly look into that, thank you.
I tried using your code and got an error with

var yourObj = (ImageTapped)img.Tag;

Is it supposed to be 

var yourObj = (Image)img.Tag;  ?

Comment: sorry it should be `var yourObj = (GridSpaces)img.Tag;`

Comment: I'm trying to further understand how to get it involved into an array. Looking at the code you gave, I think I understand it as, var img becomes the name of the image (ex. image1) and then yourObj grabs the gridspace that was assigned to that image's (ex.image1) tag. How could I assign all of them into one array? Will I have to go to through and say myGridSpace[0] = image1.tag; myGridSpace[1] = image2.tag? then whenever I grab (GridSpaces)img.Tag I need to get myGridSpace[num] again if it was updated. I feel like I'm going in circles.

Comment: why do you need index num of myGridSpace, if you need update property of GridSpaces, its enough to get from Tag and update, if you realy need the index, just use linq to find the index of GirdSpace object in array

Comment: wow, there is so much coding option I don't know. I'm feeling inexperienced but I'm willing to learn. I'm hoping I understand the code so far. If I wanted to program it so that when the user taps the image that yourObj.occupiedby = "Player1"; Does this value only exist in yourObj or is it updated in image1.tag? I would think it's the prior. so I would need to assign it into GridSpaces too? I'm using myGridSpaces array so I can easily search with a for loop through all of the spaces.

Comment: thats enough to set yourObj.occupiedby = Player1 because yourObj, tag, Girdspace[index] points to the same object (you can easily make a test toverify it) and dont need to assign again to array ( this is about object reference i think you also need to learn)

Comment: I did a test, I see. I assigned image1.tag = gridspace[0] and image.tag = gridspace[1]. Then when the user taps the image, it assigns the yourObj.occupiedby = player1 and then I had a textbox display what gridspace[0].occupiedby was, and it was player1. I really do need to understand what I'm coding more, but it's my favorite way to learn by doing. Should I keep programing making my own programs or crack open a book?

Comment: I don't know what knowledge you've already had, in my opinion, reading a book is a good choice, just read one book about the core of .net, and you will see the life is easier, good luck!